# Distinct based on two fields in sql server: .NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, group-by, distinct

I am trying to fetch the records that are unique in the table based on the two fields. The table structure is;

[image]

The problem I get with the query below;

```
var dept = db.Departments.Where(x => x.LeadBy == SessionManager.CurrentUser.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault();

var teams = db.Teams.Where(x => x.DeptID == dept.DepartmentId);

List<Employee> refinedEmpList = new List<Employee>();
var empList = db.Employees.ToList();
foreach (var v in teams)
{
    foreach (var c in empList)
    {
        if (v.TeamID == c.TeamId)
        {
            refinedEmpList.Add(c);
        }
    }
}

var CronRep = db.CronReports.ToList();
List<CronReport> EmpList = new List<CronReport>();
foreach (var v in refinedEmpList)
{
    foreach (var c in CronRep)
    {
        if (v.EmployeeId == c.EmpID)
        {
            EmpList.Add(c);
        }
    }
}

return View(EmpList.Where(x => x.Status != "Present" && x.Status != "Absent" && x.Fine != 0).ToList());
```

It displays the dup entries too like below;

[image: Dup Entries]

I tried changing the query to;

```
return View(EmpList.Where(x => x.Status != "Present" && x.Status != "Absent" && x.Fine != 0).GroupBy(x => x.EmpID).Select(x => x.First()).ToList());
```

but this as expected only shows the unique Employees like below;

[image: No dups but incorrect]

^Which is obviously not correct as I want all the employees with different datetime but no repeated records.

Comment: What are the result you expect? Its not clear which properties you want to define as being distinct

Comment: Have you had a look at GroupBy?

Comment: @StephenMuecke expected results are the same as the picture shows in dup entries, except that it should not have the entries twice as shown in the picture (notice the black lines before the records, exact same records shown twice)

Comment: @d219 I did try with it in the query above. but it isn't what I want!

Comment: @StephenMuecke In other words, one record for an employee with one datetime (no multiple datettimes for a single employee)

Comment: But they are not the same - the `Departure Time` and `Time Spent` are different! Are you wanting any records with the same `Name` and `DateTime` to be not repeated. And if so, which record do you want to display?

Comment: @StephenMuecke `Are you wanting any records with the same Name and DateTime to be not repeated` exactly! All the rest records should be displayed? like if you see the picture from 05 March 2018 to 15 March 2018 all the records should be displayed except that there should be only one from the last two

Comment: But which one? The first. or the last (or something in between if there a more that 2 matches)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Field1, x.Field2} ).Select(x => x.First()).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extensions method for future

```
   public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
            {
                var seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
                foreach (var element in source)
                    if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
                        yield return element;
            }
```

with usage

```
collection.DistinctBy(x => new {x.Field1, x.Field2}).ToList();
```